# Не получается создать класс в python

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь создать класс, чтобы чтобы при вводе положительного числа, оно добавлялось в список, а при вводе отрицательного программа писала, что число отрицательное.

Вот моё подобие кода:

```
class Spisok:
    def append(self, x):
        if x > 0:
            Spisok.append(x)
        else:
            print('Число меньше 0')

lst = Spisok
lst.append(5)
```

Я в этом деле почти совсем нулячий, прочитал уже кучу статей и посмотрел кучу роликов по ооп, но до сих пор не могу понять даже азы. Пара вопросов:

1. Надо ли здесь писать `def __init__(self)` и зачем он нужен? Я читал что эта штука инициализирует класс, кто-то называет это конструктором класса, и я не понимаю нужен ли он, потому что часто его вообще не используют в лёгких программах.
2. Как сделать, чтобы можно было вводить сразу кучу чисел, я знаю про *args, но опять же не понимаю как это реализовать. Программа не даёт мне писать if *args > 0  =\

Заранее огромное спасибо! Очень хочу во всё разобраться честно!

Comment: Конструкторы нужны для создания и инициирования полей объектов, поэтому фраза (ее считаю неверной, т.к. без конструкторов смысла в классах нет) `часто его вообще не используют в лёгких программах.` скорее всего относится к полям, относящимся к классам (а не объектам), у них есть свои особенности (либо там генераторы классов, типа @dataclass). В вашем случае, вам точно понадобится создавать конструктор, а в нем создать поле, содержащее список, в который вы и будете методом `append` добавлять значения. Второй вариант, это создание наследника от класса `list` и переопределение его метода `append`

Comment: Я вот до сих пор путаюсь в терминологии... Объект - это то, что часто называют экземпляром? т.е. в строке lst = Spisok() , lst - это и есть объект\экземпляр?

Comment: Да, lst это экземпляр класса. Экземпляр класса 'spisok' означает, что он принадлежит к классy 'spisok'. А объект хранит конкретные значения свойств, и может выполнять методы(append)

Comment: Ничегошеньки не понял=\ т.е. это всё таки разные вещи? lst ведь тоже может выполнять методы... lst.append :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод `__init__` выполняется при создании каждого нового экземпляра класса.
Грyбо говоря в твоём слyчае каждый раз при создани экземпляра класса Spisok, мы создаем пyстой список self.lst. Первый аргумент, self, он получает от интерпретатора, остальные передаются классу в круглых скобках при создании экземпляра.

```
class Spisok:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []

    def append(self, x):
        if x > 0:
            self.lst.append(x)
        else:
            print('Число меньше 0')


lst = Spisok()
lst.append(5)
lst.append(-5)
```

Есть еще вопросы?

Comment: "_Есть еще вопросы?_" — Как сделать, чтобы можно было вводить сразу кучу чисел?

Comment: def append(*args): *args берёт все вводимые значения за 1 раз, и добавляет их в кортеж. Не обязательно писать именно *args, можно любое дрyгое название, только со знаком * в начале. Чтобы потом обратится к *args, надо писать не "*args",  а "args".

Comment: Я сейчас так попробовал, но программа пишет 
`if args > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'`

Comment: args это кортеж со всеми вводимыми за 1 раз  значениями.

Comment: значит, чтобы мне проверить все значения на принадлежность к > 0 надо их типа прогнать через какой-нибудь цикл  for ?

Comment: Да. Ведь значений не одно.

Answer (score 2):

Вам прямая дорога читать о магических методах и продолжать изучать ООП.

`__init__` - инициализатор нового экземпляра.
Где использовать? Везде. Пока что.
К примеру у вас есть класс человека. У людей есть имена. Одно на всех? Нет. Так инициализатор решает это как лучший друг.

```
class человек(object):
    расса = "человек он, вроде."
    def __init__(self, name: str = "TobaSko"):
        self.name = name
```

В этом случае для каждого человека мы передадим его индивидуальное имя. Имя (self.name) будет дано каждому экземпляру при его инициализации:

```
a = человек()
b = человек("Shamus_Rezol")

print(a.name, b.name, sep = " vs ")
```

```
TobaSko vs Shamus_Rezol
```

Конечно же, его можно поменять и после, но, в основном, только если у тебя нету инициализатора, что не очень то и **удобно** (ключевое слово: удобства):

```
class человек(object): pass
a = человек()
a.name = "Комментатор"
```

---

Звездочка знаменует то, что аргумент передастся как кортеж (tuple), а при сдвоеной как словарь (dict). После них бессконечность аргументов. Первый тип - просто аргументы. Второй тип - именованые аргументы (немножко = True).

```
def Ломай(*arguments, **options):
    print(type(arguments), type(options), sep = "; ")
    
    options.setdefault("немножко", False)
    
    if options["немножко"]:
        print("Совсем уж немножко ", end = str())
    
    for argument in arguments:
        print(argument, end = ' ')
    
    print(str())# 2 NL (\n)

Ломай("изогнул шею", "и пробил болевой", немножко = True, не_бей_кома_обос = "передастся и будет в options, но попросту проигнорируется за отсутствием реализации")
```

```
<class 'tuple'>; <class 'dict'>
Совсем уж немножко изогнул шею и пробил болевой
```

### Ваши лучшие друзья

Это type и dir. Нелепо обходить их стороной при изучении языка. Очень хорошие штуки, делающие штучки. Эксперименты, эмперический путь и только! Чуть не забыл. GOOGLE.COM тоже.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, за столь развёрнутый ответ! 
Я только ещё полтора месяца изучаю язык и информации просто куча. Я знаю и про dir и про type, я уже даже знаю про mro и линеаризацию) Но это тот случай, когда есть куча инструментов и полное отсутствие способности к использованию оных. Я пересмотрел кучу виде на ютубе и почитал уже не одну тройку статей, но покамест в голове каша. Буду очень признателен, если вы посоветуете хорошее пособие, с помощью которого можно поднабраться "базы" по ооп.

Comment: Моим пособием всю жизнь были другие люди. «Минговать» чужие коды, чуть их модифицировать, спрашивать других - вот и понеслость. В жизни ни к одной книжке по программированию не обращался. Разве что совсем недавно нашел кое что интересное **для себя** (Марк Саммерфилд - Python на практике (2014)). В целом 7-8 лет естественного неспешно идущего опыта и научился прогить (в python'е 2 года, только на интерпретируемых языках). Язык я изучаю методом интересно - разбирайся. К примеру про mro и линеризацию только сейчас и услышал. Все, что я делал, это изучал разные части языка на конкретных задачах.

Comment: Думаю, «каша в голове» - это случай новичка. То есть у меня такая же ситуация с c#. Где  то так же полотора месяца изучаю по справочнику, много в чем шарю и это при том,  что уже чутка знаком с си подобным синтаксисом, но вот применить это уже проблематично. Просто нет наработанной установки что где да как будет лучше использовать.